# JQuery - If ( $('#products').existOn.(document) ) == true { //do this }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can I make this conditional branch.. If the  with the ID products is in the HTML code? If #products does exist in the actual document?

Thank you for your response!

Pseudo Javascript (JQuery)

```
If ( $('#products').existOn.(document) ) == true { 
   //do this
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to vary the `document` part, you'd do something like this:

```
if( $(document).find('#products').length > 0 ) {
   // do this
}
```

If it'll always be `document`, it'll suffice to do

```
if( $('#products').length > 0 ) {
   // do this
}
```

An alternative approach of achieving the first example would be to pass a context parameter as a second argument:

```
if( $('#products', document).length > 0 ) {
   // do this
}
```

Note that the context parameter should be a DOM node, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
if ( $('#products').length > 0){ 
   // element is present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with jQuery?

```
if (document.getElementById('products')) {
  //do this
}
```

Comment: As is so often the answer to 'why jQuery' questions: for cross-browser consistency. Given `<input name="products" />`, your condition would yield an object in IE6 and `null` in most browsers.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Matthieu - I disagree.  The author asked how to identify if an element with a given ID existed in the document, and I gave him a solution (albeit, it will also detect items with that name in IE6/7).